# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toFixed')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to javascript, and I'm trying to get my `totalProfit` to show on my order list page. I keep getting a **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toFixed')** Below I have included what I have. I would really appreciate any help or advice on why I'm having this issue. Thank you!

OrderListScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { deleteOrder, listOrders } from '../actions/orderActions';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import { ORDER_DELETE_RESET } from '../constants/orderConstants';

export default function OrderListScreen(props) {
  const sellerMode = props.match.path.indexOf('/seller') >= 0;
  const orderList = useSelector((state) => state.orderList);
  const { loading, error, orders } = orderList;
  const orderDelete = useSelector((state) => state.orderDelete);
  const {
    loading: loadingDelete,
    error: errorDelete,
    success: successDelete,
  } = orderDelete;

  const userSignin = useSelector((state) => state.userSignin);
  const { userInfo } = userSignin;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: ORDER_DELETE_RESET });
    dispatch(listOrders({ seller: sellerMode ? userInfo._id : '' }));
  }, [dispatch, sellerMode, successDelete, userInfo._id]);
  const deleteHandler = (order) => {
    // TODO: delete handler
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure to delete?')) {
        dispatch(deleteOrder(order._id));
      }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Orders</h1>
      {loadingDelete && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
      {errorDelete && <MessageBox variant="danger">{errorDelete}</MessageBox>}
      {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>USER</th>
              <th>DATE</th>
              <th>TOTAL</th>
              <th>PAID</th>
              <th>DELIVERED</th>
              <th>SHIPPED</th>
              <th>RETURNED</th>
              <th>PROFIT</th>
              <th>ACTIONS</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {orders.map((order) => (
              <tr key={order._id}>
                <td>{order._id}</td>
                <td>{order.username}</td>
                <td>{order.createdAt.substring(0, 10)}</td>
                <td>{order.totalPrice.toFixed(2)}</td>
                <td>{order.isPaid ? order.paidAt.substring(0, 10) : 'No'}</td>
                <td>
                  {order.isDelivered
                    ? order.deliveredAt.substring(0, 10)
                    : 'No'}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {order.isShipped
                    ? order.ShippedAt.substring(0, 10)
                    : 'No'}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {order.isReturned
                    ? order.ReturnedAt.substring(0, 10)
                    : 'No'}
                </td>
                <td>{order.totalProfit.toFixed(2)}</td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="small"
                    onClick={() => {
                      props.history.push(`/order/${order._id}`);
                    }}
                  >
                    Details
                  </button>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="small"
                    onClick={() => deleteHandler(order)}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

PlaceOrderScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {createOrder,  } from '../actions/orderActions';
import CheckoutSteps from '../components/CheckoutSteps';
import { ORDER_CREATE_RESET } from '../constants/orderConstants';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';

export default function PlaceOrderScreen(props) {
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  if (!cart.paymentMethod) {
    props.history.push('/payment');
  }
  const orderCreate = useSelector((state) => state.orderCreate);
  const { loading, success, error, order } = orderCreate;
  const toPrice = (num) => Number(num.toFixed(2)); // 5.123 => "5.12" => 5.12
  cart.itemsPrice = toPrice(
    cart.cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.qty * c.price, 0)
  );
  cart.shippingPrice = cart.itemsPrice > 39.99 ? toPrice(0) : toPrice(10);
  {
   cart.taxPrice = toPrice(0.065 * cart.itemsPrice)}
  cart.totalPrice = cart.itemsPrice + cart.shippingPrice + cart.taxPrice;

  //
  const toProfit = (num) => Number(num.toFixed(2)); // 5.123 => "5.12" => 5.12
  cart.itemsProfit= toProfit(
    cart.cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.qty * c.profit, 0)
  );
  
  cart.totalProfit = cart.itemsProfit;
  //
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const placeOrderHandler = () => {
    dispatch(createOrder({ ...cart, orderItems: cart.cartItems }));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (success) {
      props.history.push(`/order/${order._id}`);
      dispatch({ type: ORDER_CREATE_RESET });
    }
  }, [dispatch, order, props.history, success]);
  return (
    <div>
      <CheckoutSteps step1 step2 step3 step4></CheckoutSteps>
      <div className="row top">
        <div className="col-2">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div className="card card-body">
                <h2>Order Items</h2>
                <ul>
                  {cart.cartItems.map((item) => (
                    <li key={item.product}>
                      <div className="row">
                        <div>
                          <img
                            src={item.image}
                            alt={item.name}
                            className="small"
                          ></img>
                        </div>
                        <div className="min-30">
                          <Link to={`/product/${item.product}`}>
                            {item.name}
                          </Link>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                          {item.qty} x ${item.price} = ${item.qty * item.price}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="col-1">
          <div className="card card-body">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <h2>Order Summary</h2>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div className="row">
                  <div>Items</div>
                  <div>${cart.itemsPrice.toFixed(2)}</div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div className="row">
                  <div>Shipping</div>
                  <div>${cart.shippingPrice.toFixed(2)}</div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div className="row">
                  <div>Tax</div>
                  <div>${cart.taxPrice.toFixed(2)}</div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div className="row">
                  <div>
                    <strong> Order Total</strong>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <strong>${cart.totalPrice.toFixed(2)}</strong>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={placeOrderHandler}
                  className="primary block"
                  disabled={cart.cartItems.length === 0}
                >
                  Place Order
                </button>
              </li>
              {loading && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
              {error && <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Backend

OrderModel.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    orderItems: [
      {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        qty: { type: Number, required: true },
        image: { type: String, required: true },
        price: { type: Number, required: true },
        profit: { type: Number, required: true },
        product: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'Product',
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
    shippingAddress: {
      fullName: { type: String, required: true },
      address: { type: String, required: true },
      city: { type: String, required: true },
      postalCode: { type: String, required: true },
      country: { type: String, required: true },
    },
    paymentMethod: { type: String, required: true },
    paymentResult: {
        id: String,
        status: String,
        update_time: String,
        email_address: String,
      },
    itemsPrice: { type: Number, required: true },
    shippingPrice: { type: Number, required: true },
    taxPrice: { type: Number, required: true },
    totalPrice: { type: Number, required: true },
    itemsProfit: { type: Number, required: true },
    totalProfit: { type: Number, required: true },
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    seller: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref: 'User' },
    isPaid: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    paidAt: { type: Date },
    isDelivered: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    isShipped: {type: Boolean, default: false },
    isReturned: {type: Boolean, default: false },
    deliveredAt: { type: Date },
    shippedAt:  { type: Date },
    ReturnedAt:  { type: Date },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);




const Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
export default Order;
```

Answer (score 2):

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toFixed')

This error's cause is simple literally.

When you use `toFixed()` with some variable and that variable is `undefined`, that error occurred.

I found `toFixed()` in your code a lot but there is no code for `undefined` case.

you just add `?` like this

```
num?.toFixed();
cart?.totalPrice?.toFixed(2)
...
```

Comment: what about add a default value? for example `num?.toFixed() || "0.00";` or
`cart?.totalPrice?.toFixed(2) || "0.00"`.

Comment: @kyun, thank you, I think I might not have explained my problem properly. I understand that it's saying that totalProfit is undefined, but I don't understand why it is saying that for totalProfit when it isn't saying it for totalPrice. Also, the ```num?.toFixed();``` gave me a syntax error with for the question mark.

Comment: @kyun I was actually having this error because mongodb wasn't registering totalProfit

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I was receiving this error because mongodb wasn't registering my `totalProfit` variable, so it was being treated as if it was undefined.